# Processing camera frames on Android

Tags: android

i want to use my android phone to process image, for example, make any 
operation with de frame and show it with the change (show the image in 
black/white, grayscale, sepia, etc). 
This is my code:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,PreviewCallback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
    Camera mCamera;

    private Parameters parameters; 
    private Size previewSize; 
    private int[] pixels; 
    public CameraPreview(Context context) { 
    super(context); 
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = getHolder(); 
    mHolder.addCallback(this); 
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL); 
    this.setFocusable(true); 
    this.requestFocus(); 
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    mCamera = Camera.open(); 
} 

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    mCamera.stopPreview(); 
    mCamera.release(); 
    mCamera = null; 
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { 
setImageSize(); 
mCamera.startPreview(); 
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this); 
}
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
    // transforms NV21 pixel data into RGB pixels 
    decodeYUV420SP(pixels, data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height); 
    //here process the image 
    }
}
```

the problem is that i don't know how to show the new image processed. 
In onPreviewFrame I convert yuv to rgb, then I process the image i.e. 
convert in grayscale, but what i do for show the new image? 
I need help, thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using OpenCV or looking at one of their samples for image manipulations:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

Answer (score 0):

I read an article at: http://nhenze.net/?p=107
From what I read in the post, it's not very easy to do, because the onPreviewFrame is not synced with displaying the frames.

Instead, they use a trick to set another view on top of the SurfaceView. On that new View, they render images on an OpenGL texture with OpenGL ES.

I haven't played with it myself, but hope this will put you in the right direction.